# I want to show ActionBar menu when Device orienation is changed

Tags: oncreateoptionsmenu

I am trying to show the ActionBar Menu in fragments, When device orientation is changed from portrait to landscape or vice versa Menu is dismissed. I want to show menu when device orientation is also changed.

I don't  want to provide a `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a new `layout-land`, that will change when the device is rotated.
 
Check this video/class from Google, maybe will help you :
https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud851/lessons/92320789-2acc-42cc-9d64-b1d0e5f1947a/concepts/d0a07b3a-9654-47fd-8079-9970a888b9b9

Comment: No , No layout changes, I just want to show the opened action menu when device orientation is changed.

Comment: And if you make a variable (or function) to verify the `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` ?